# How do I invoke a servlet from my android application?

Tags: android, servlets, invoke

I am absolutely new to android development and I need help in know how can I invoke a remote servlet which is gonna send me data from a database in the form of xml. I am a beginner and I don't understand jargon. If possible provide me with a link/tutorial for the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this while making a get request.

```
public boolean funtionAtSite(String sentUrl) {
        String url = sentUrl;
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            ResponseHandler<String> reponseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = client.execute(getMethod, reponseHandler);
            /******** now do what you want to do with response **********/
            if (responseBody.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                Log.v(TAG, responseBody);
                return true;
            }
                return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to invoke a servlet and use its response object back in my application, your code didnt solve my problem, please check again.

Comment: Ok Friend what are you getting in response object from servlet

Comment: Illegal State exception. It has nothing, it is going directly to other catch block.

Comment: Have you added Internet access permission in AndroidManifest.xml. This could shud work I 'm using it.